# positioning background image of div using javascript

Tags: javascript, image, positioning, crop, clipping

I am trying to make a clipping window but it is not happening, here is the code sample:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #clippingWindow
        {
            height:178px;
            width:278px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #bgImg
        {
            left:35px;
            border:54px;
        }
    </style>
    <script language="javascript">

        function getImgSize()
        {

            var ds = document.getElementsByName('a');
            var wid = ds[0].width;
            var pos = (wid-278)/2;

            alert(pos);
            alert(ds[0].id);

            if(ds[0].width>278)
            {
                dt.style.left=500; //this is not working
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body><input type="button" onClick="getImgSize();">
    <div id="clippingWindow">
        <img name="a" src="sss.bmp" id="bgImg">
    </div><br><br><br>
    <div id="ad">
        <img name="a" src="484.jpeg">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to set the `position` property of the element you want to position to something like `absolute` or `relative` (e.g. `ds.style.position = "relative";`). The `left` property doesn't have any effect on statically positioned elements.

Also, you probably need to use `"500px"` instead of the number `500`.

Comment: there is javascript a error "'style' is null or not an object"

Answer (score 1):

I see three issues:

1. `dt.style.left=500;` should be `ds.style.left=500; (but see point #3)`
2. You need to position your `#bgImg` element. Ex: `position:relative;`
3. Most browsers should be OK with your 500 unit in the line `ds.style.left=500;` however `dts.style.left='500px';` would be better.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vZ6PY/1/)**

Comment: still it is not working... there is a javascript error "'style' is null or not an object"

Comment: @BharatSoni - are you getting that error in the jsFiddle or on your site?

Comment: So if it's working in the fiddle but not on your site then there must be other code that is interfering.

Comment: i want to clip a picture dynamically according to its width....if you have a better solution please give me that....or please repair this code...

Comment: [machine happy](http://machinehappy.com/) under #latest category... here i want to use this thing

Answer (score 0):

you must set the css property "left" with a value and a measurement such as "500px" (you forgot the px)